# exc bad access when change the contentSize of popover

Tags: macos, cocoa, exc-bad-access, nspopover, contentsize

I have a button to trigger the popover, and a checkbox on the popover. The state checkbox of the checkbox is bound to a field 'checkboxState' of an NSManagedObject.

Here is the scenario:

1. I click the button, the popover will show up.
2. I check the checkbox on the popover, then the popover becomes larger and some other views are shown (if I uncheck the checkbox, the views will be hidden, and the popover goes back to the original size). **The checkboxState is YES here**
3. I close the popover, and do some other stuff which will **change the checkboxState to NO**.
4. I click the button again, then the app hangs for about 10 seconds and the xcode throws EXC_BAD_ACCESS(code=2, address=0x7fff5f3ffff8),    the caller is 0_CFArrayReplaceValues

**The app doesn't die, it just doesn't respond.**

The button's action is as following:

```
- (IBAction)showPopover:(id)sender {
    if (!_myPopover) {
        _myPopover = [[NSPopover alloc] init];
        _myPopover.delegate = self;
        _myPopover.contentViewController = self;
        _myPopover.animates = YES;
        _myPopover.behavior = NSPopoverBehaviorSemitransient;
        _myPopover.appearance = NSPopoverAppearanceMinimal;
    }

    id theManagedObject = self.myArrayController.selection;
    BOOL state = [[theManagedObject valueForKey:@"checkboxState"] boolValue];   

    if (state) {        
        _myPopover.contentSize = NSMakeSize(360, 340);
        [self.view1 setHidden:NO];
        [self.view2 setHidden:NO];
    }
    else {
        [self.view1 setHidden:YES];
        [self.view2 setHidden:YES];
        _myPopover.contentSize = NSMakeSize(360, 270);
    }

    [_myPopover showRelativeToRect:[sender bounds] ofView:sender preferredEdge:NSMaxYEdge];
}
```

The code that changes the checkboxState of the object is:
`[anManagedObject setValue:@NO forKey:@"checkboxState"]`

If I comment the `_myPopover.contentSize = NSMakeSize(360, 270)` in showPopover; it will work.

If I comment the `[anManagedObject setValue:@NO forKey:@"checkboxState"]` , it will work

I used `@try @catch`, no error thrown. I used the Profile tool, it seems the app goes into an infinite loop, and the memory usage goes up very quickly. The possible callers that cause this are `[NSLayoutConstaint _loweredExpressionReportingConstantIsRounded:]` and `[NSIsObjectiveLinearExpression replaceVariable:withExpression:processVariableNewToReceiver:processVariableDroppedFromReceiver:]`

Any ideas? I have been stuck at this problem for a day. Really need to solve this.

EDIT:
The issues occurs at 25th second. A lot of memory alloced after that. 
[image: The issues occurs at 25th second.]

From the object list, I see the following stuff, and they are repeatedly called until the end. 
[image]

Comment: When you run this under Instruments with the Zombies template, what do you find?

Comment: @PeterHosey I didn't find anything specific. Maybe it's because I don't know how to use it. By looking at the caller list, I suspect it goes into infinite loop. I worked around the problem by re-creating the popover view when necessary, but I'd happy to know what caused the  issue.

Comment: If the problem is caused by messaging a dead object, running it under Zombies will cause a flag to appear in Instruments's timeline at the moment when that occurs. What's the stack trace that leads you to suspect an “infinite loop”?

Comment: By the way: `EXC_BAD_ACCESS` means your process *did* die.

Comment: There's not any flag, and the timeline continues even the app doesn't respond. I will post the screenshot of the instrument's timeline.

Comment: What happens if you take a couple of heapshots during that slope, about 5 seconds apart, and look at the latter heapshot? What objects have been created? Where are they created?

Comment: You might also do the same with Zombies turned off, although you may not see the slope in that experiment (Zombies disables deallocation; instead of dying, objects become zombie objects, and zombie objects still count toward the graph).